# get data from column using one common field?

Tags: php, mysql

table exp_channel_data as ecd:

```
id | field_id_16| img_src

1  |  2        | a.jpg
2  |  1        | b.jpg
3  |  3        | c.jpg
```

table pin_info as pi:

```
id | look_week | member_id | is_pinned

1  |  2        | 2         | yes
2  |  1        | 2         | yes
3  |  3        | 1         | yes
```

**What I want to do:**

get an array of img src from table ecd for a member(lets say 2) and is_pinned=yes.The only common field i have is field_id_16 and look_week.

**What I have done:**

```
$sql="
  SELECT 
    ecd.field_id_17 as pin_img
  FROM exp_channel_data ecd
  WHERE 
     ecd.field_id_16=(
       SELECT look_week 
       FROM pin_info pi 
       WHERE
         pi.member_id='$member_id' 
         AND is_pinned='yes'
     )
";
```

I am unable to get the array.The error is *Subquery returns more than 1 row*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saying correct because you have two rows with member id 2 try with join

```
SELECT ecd.img_src as pin_img FROM exp_channel_data ecd 
JOIN pin_info pi ON (ecd.field_id_16 = pi.look_week )
WHEHER pi.member_id='$member_id' AND pi.is_pinned='yes'
```

i guess you don't have `field_id_17` in `exp_channel_data`

Comment: what if i used `JOIN ecd ON`..i mean why joi pin_info and not ecd..i got the result..just wanted to ask

Comment: you have mentioned ecd already after from clause so ecd will be join with pin_info table

Comment: it gives me an array inside an array..do all the joins give you the result in same pattern?

Comment: joins only gives you the desired data set this depends on you how you manipulate the data by using any serverside languages join don't relate to array ,arrays are in  serverside languages not in mysql query

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    ecd.field_id_17 as pin_img
  FROM exp_channel_data ecd
  WHERE 
     ecd.field_id_16 IN (
       SELECT look_week 
       FROM pin_info pi 
       WHERE
         pi.member_id='$member_id' 
         AND is_pinned='yes')
```

Comment: can you explain that where clause?

Comment: WHERE 
     ecd.field_id_16 IN(2,1) based on the subquery.IN is for multiple values.